# VIM , how to show the count of occurrence the current match pattern under cursor?

Tags: vim, match

How to show the count of occurrence the current match pattern under cursor ?
For example:

```
aa
bb
aab   searching aa, cursor is here, show 2. 
aa
bb
```

And how to insert the number 2  after the line . "aab" -> "aab 2"

Comment: I see three `aa` in text blob. I don't really get what you are trying to do

Comment: I'm confused myself. Is it supposed to say "2" because you are on the 2nd match out of 3 matches? Because there are 2 other occurrences of "aa"? What?

Comment: the line of aab is where the 2th occurrence of aa.

Comment: If the bottom line of vim shows the N/sum (sum is count sum of occurrence, and N is the N'th of occurrence.) is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a function and a mapping to do the job (add these lines to the end of your .vimrc; it needs at least vim 7.4 and `nocompatible` to be set before it):

```
nnoremap  X  :call Count( '<C-R>=expand( '<cWORD>' )<CR>' )<CR>

function! Count( word )
  redir => cnt
    silent exe '%s/' . a:word . '//n'
  redir END
  silent exe 's/.*/& ' . matchstr( cnt, '\d\+' ) . '/'
endfunction
```

If you pressing `X` on a WORD (**bordered with withespace characters**), the `Count` function will add the count of the same words in the file to the end of the actual line.

To add the ordinal number, change `Count` to `NthCount` in the mapping and add these lines to .vimrc:

```
function! NthCount( word )
  redir => nth
    silent exe '0,.s/' . a:word . '//n'
  redir => cnt
    silent exe '%s/' . a:word . '//n'
  redir END
  silent exe 's/.*/& ' . matchstr( nth, '\d\+' ) . '/'
  echo a:word . ': ' . matchstr( nth, '\d\+' ) . '/' . matchstr( cnt, '\d\+' )
endfunction
```

For example pressing it on the first `bb`:

```
aa
bb 1
aab
aa
bb
-- STATUSLINE --
bb: 1/2
```

Comment: Not having to edit, getting the information of the Nth occurrence under the cursor is OK.

Comment: Thanks, maybe you misunderstand me. I want to insert the number N, that is Nth occurrence. If the bottom line of vim shows the format like N/sum (sum is count sum of occurrence, and N is the N'th of occurrence.) will be better

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want (lost in translation), but i hope the modified answer helps.